# How to decrypt video using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, encryption, video-encoding, decryption

I've managed to encrypt my video files using the `ffmpeg` command below;
however, I can't find a way to save the decrypted output.

```
ffmpeg -i {file} -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key {key} -encryption_kid {checksum} e.mp4
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939166/ffmpeg-how-to-produce-mp4-cenc-common-encryption-videos/44949160#44949160) has an example for playing the video back using `ffplay`,
which works, but I want to save the output to a file and want it done faster than normal playback speed.

I also tried using `-decryption_key`, but I get

> Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found

when processing input with this command

```
ffmpeg -i {file} -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -decryption_key {key} d.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681293/how-can-i-decrypt-the-encrypted-mp4-file-using-ffmpeg)

You should use -decryption_key as input option.

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key {key} -i {file} -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 d.mp4
```

Comment: `-max_muxing_queue_size` doesn't seem to speed it up though

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below ffmpeg command for file decryption.

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key {key} -i {file} -vcodec libx264 {output_file}
```